# SQL rank and partition

Tags: sql, window-functions

using this query

```
SELECT STC.*, rank() over (partition by service_id order by service_tracking_id desc) rnk
FROM pntt.ntt_service_tracking_curr stc
where service_id in 
('61NA',
```

and the response is

```
rnk service_id service_tracking_id
1   61NA    7112415
2   61NA    5202885
3   61NA    44427875
4   61NA    2390953
5   61NA    117139
6   61NA    117138
7   61NA    10586781
```

Why is it ranking this way? Does it have something to do with the type of field that Service_id is? Does it need to be cast as an integer or is it something to do with the length of the field?

Comment: so I can rank and add the rank nr within the service_id as above but how do I only pull those records with a rnk of 1 into the query rather than seeing all records? Thanks,

Answer (score 0):

Because `service_tracking_id` is a string, so the ordering is alphabetical rather than numeric.

Here is one way to fix it:

```
SELECT STC.*,
       rank() over (partition by service_id
                    order by length(service_tracking_id) desc, service_tracking_id desc  -- might be len
                    ) rnk
```

Alternatively, cast the value to a decimal:

```
SELECT STC.*,
       rank() over (partition by service_id
                    order by cast(service_tracking_id as decimal(20, 2)) desc
                    ) rnk
```

Comment: SELECT STC.*,
rank() over (partition by service_id order by cast(service_tracking_id as int) desc) rnk
FROM pntt.ntt_service_tracking_curr stc
where service_id in

Comment: @KevinTempleton . . . If your string values fit in an integer, that that will also work.  I used decimal because it has a wider range.